# Unable to stream openAI response from a fastify server

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, openai-api, fastify

I am banging my head against the wall with something which should be so very simple! Just to call the openAI API and return the stream from the fastify server.

I have seen the docs and streams are looking super simple:

```
fastify.get('/streams', async function (request, reply) {
  const fs = require('node:fs')
  const stream = fs.createReadStream('some-file', 'utf8')
  reply.header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
  return reply.send(stream)
})
```

However when trying to hook this up to the openAI call:

```js
async function main() {
  const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: 'gpt-4',
    messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Say this is a test' }],
    stream: true,
  });
  for await (const part of stream) {
    process.stdout.write(part.choices[0]?.delta?.content || '');
  }
}
```

I just cannot get it to work....

I have tried:

- passing the stream directly
- passing the stream in an async loop
- using the raw HTTP request in fastify
- converting to readableStream

Nothing seems to work

Here is my latest attempt:

```js
app.get<{ Querystring: GetSearchParams }>('/stream', async (req, reply) => {
  try {
    const { q } = req.query;
    const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: q }],
      stream: true,
    });

    reply.raw.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });

    for await (const part of stream) {
      console.log(part.choices[0]?.delta?.content || '');
      reply.raw.write(part.choices[0]?.delta?.content || '');
    }
    reply.raw.end();
  } catch (err) {
    reply.raw.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    reply.raw.end('Ooops');
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any errors or warning ?

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```js
app.get<{ Querystring: GetSearchParams }>('/stream', async (req, reply) => {
  try {
    const { q } = req.query;
    const stream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: q }],
      stream: true,
    });

    reply.raw.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    for await (const part of stream) {
      reply.raw.write(part.choices[0]?.delta?.content || '');
    }
    return reply.raw.end();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    reply.raw.end('Error sending chat stream.');
  }
});
```